# How to get the rows of an html table with tidylib in C?

Tags: html, c, dom, tidy

As I ask in the title, I can't get the rows of an html tabl in C using tidylib. I have read the documentation at http://tidy.sourceforge.net/docs/api/ but I really can't find what I want.

After a CURL call, I save the result in a file or in a variable; but then can't go on.

Thank you.

Comment: @Reda How do you get the content of an html tag having the whole html in a string?

Answer (score 1):

i used a html parser the way you want to do now, and i highly recommend using the libxml HTML parser rather than tidy, libxml is widely used and documented. you can find the docs here : http://www.xmlsoft.org/html/libxml-HTMLparser.html

And i don't think someone will reply help you with a good code because tidyc is not used widely and not for this type of tasks.